# Loading .properties file in a jar from my web-app

Tags: spring, jar

I have created a JAR that I need to use in my WEB-APP. Both are created with spring framework. I would like to load a .properties file outside the JAR file, in the main context of the web-application. And I want to do it with the facilities that Spring offers us.

I've tried to do something like this in my spring.xml file inside the JAR:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
       <value>/WEB-INF/classes/my.properties</value>
</property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
   <property name="triggers">
      <bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
         <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob" />
     <property name="cronExpression" value="${my.cronExpression}"/>
      </bean>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Trying to load my.cronExpression from my.properties file. But without any success.

I always get this error:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'my.cronExpression'.

I've tried to change the location with many variants, using classpath:/WEB-INF/classes/my.properties etc...

But I'm not able to load the configuration file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use classpath:my.properties - /WEB-INF/classes is root of your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring it as follows:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
       <value>/WEB-INF/classes/my.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders">
       <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code and want you to try this code snippet

It works well for me :)

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location" value="file:/WEB-INF/classes/my.properties" />
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
<property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```